# JQuery limits RSS feed to 4 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I have this code that I am using to import an RSS feed via JQuery. My problem is that it only imports 4 RSS items and then stops. Any idea why this might be?

```
$.fn.rssWidget = function(feedUrl, dateFormat){
var dateFormatF = dateFormat || 'day/month/year hours:minutes';
var googleFeedUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0';
var title = '<h4 class="rsswidget-feed" style="display:none;"><a href=":url">:title</a></h2>';
var item = '<hr/><h5 class="rsswidget-title" style="display:none;"><a href=":url">:title</a></h3><p class="rsswidget-date" style="display:none;">:date</p><div class="rsswidget-content">:text</div>';
$(this).each(function(){
    var $that = $(this);
    var feed = $(this).attr('feed') || feedUrl;
    feed = encodeURIComponent(feed);
    $.getJSON(googleFeedUrl
        + '&q=' + feed
        + '&callback=?'
        ,function(d){
            var f = d.responseData.feed;
            console.log(f);
            $that.html(title.replace(':url', f.link).replace(':title', f.title));
            $(f.entries).each(function(i,e){
                var date = new Date(e.publishedDate);
                var dateString = dateFormatF
                .replace('day', date.getDate() < 9 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate())
                .replace('month', (date.getMonth() + 1) < 9 ? '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1) : date.getMonth() + 1)
                .replace('year', date.getFullYear())
                .replace('hours', date.getHours() < 9 ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours())
                .replace('minutes', date.getMinutes() < 9 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes())
                ;
                $that.append(item
                    .replace(':title', e.title)
                    .replace(':url', e.link)
                    .replace(':text', e.content)
                    .replace(':date', dateString));
            });
        });
});
```

And then I drop this into my HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
              $("div#feed").rssWidget('RSS FEED URL');
            });
            </script>
                <div id="feed"></div>
```

Comment: google ajax feed service is deprecated .. see the google docs

Comment: @charlietfl even by following the steps listed here https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide I'm still limited to four items.

Comment: I understand and at the top it clearly states service is deprecated. It might be they are delivering limited responses so people find out without it breaking. I actually tried using it not too long ago and had same issue. Try YQL instead

Comment: @charlietfl ok will look into YQL. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Switched to YPL and followed the docs [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-tutorials.html#tutorial-first_yql_app) for a solution.